# const object modification using reference

Tags: c++, object, reference, constants

When a function takes a parameter as a `reference` to a `const object`, I understand that the object passed as argument to it cannot be modified using the `reference`? So is there any scenarios in C++ where a `const object` can be modified through a reference to it? If yes, show an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ has a feature called `mutable` where a data member may be changed *even through a const reference*:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int a;
    mutable int b;
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.a = 1; // ok
    f.b = 2; // ok
    const Foo &g = f;
    g.a = 1; // compile error
    g.b = 2; // ok
}
```

I get the following error:

```
In function 'int main()':
Line 12: error: assignment of data-member 'Foo::a' in read-only structure
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

However, the assignment `g.b = 2;` succeeds.

This feature is usually used for `private` member variables only, where the changing of the data member does not affect the outside visible const-ness of the object. For example, it could be used as an optimisation to provide a way to cache previously calculated values.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain more on `This feature is usually used for private member variables only`

Comment: Just what it says really. If you have a `public mutable` member variable like in the example above, then the `const` doesn't really mean anything useful because the public part of the object can visibly change even through a `const` reference. On the other hand, if a `private mutable` member variable only does something internal like cache previously calculated results, then the *public* part of the object doesn't visibly change behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can always cast away the `const`-ness using `const_cast`; this may lead to undefined behaviour if you're not careful.

I guess you could also contrive something like this:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    mutable int x;

public:
    void bar() const { x++; }
};

void func(const Foo &foo)
{
    foo.bar();
    // foo is now modified!
}
```

Comment: The specific question is *is there any scenarios in C++ where a const object can be modified through a reference to it?*. Technically, if the object *is* const then casting away const-ness and using that to modify it will be Undefined Behavior *always*